# Python how to sort a list with list elements

Tags: python

How can i sort a list in python?
I have this list:

```
list=[[[1,2,3],0],[[13,2,3],2],[[2,0,0],13]]
```

And i want to sort by second element from first list.
I've think that should be something like this .

```
list.sort(key=lambda x:x[0[1]])
```

And I don't know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing is wrong. You want to index the list, not the integer.

```
list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, its simple enough:

```
>>> l=[[[1,2,3],0],[[13,2,3],2],[[2,0,0],13]]
>>> sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0][1])
[[[2, 0, 0], 13], [[1, 2, 3], 0], [[13, 2, 3], 2]]
```